# Link textboxes in InDesign so that resizing one moves the others

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I am working in Adobe InDesign. If I have a textbox below another textbox, is there a way to link them or something so that if I adjust the top text box, the bottom one moves up or down to keep the same distance between it and the top one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anchor second one in first one and set the second frame anchored settings to custom so you can relocate the frame by reference to the first frame. That way, resizing the first frame will move the second frame accordingly ;)